# SQL Azure Link DB

Tags: sql, database, azure-sql-database, sharding, multiple-databases

I have a SQL Azure Server (DBn), I need to copy some of the tables from (DBn) to number of other SQL Azure Servers (DBn1,DBn2,....). I should be able to execute the copy operation through a worker role. Is this possible via Linked server feature in SQL Azure?

Answer (score 2):

that's a common misconception about the linked server support for Azure SQL Database.

you can setup Azure SQL Database as a linked server in SQL Server but you cannot setup a linked server from Azure SQL Database itself that links to other Azure SQL Database or SQL Server.

you can add an Azure SQL Database as linked server. you cannot add a linked server in Azure SQL Database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Windows Azure SQL Data Sync where you can perform synchronization between SQL Databases on Windows Azure as well as instances of SQL Server on-premisse